Issue w/ dynamic google maps markers with marker clusterer(likely a misuse of useEffect/useRef)
I'm trying to use marker clusterer with filters for the markers, initially all markers are shown/listed on the map, when a filter(a checkbox input) is checked/applied, only a subset of the markers should be re-rendered/added. When a filter is unchecked, the coresponding markers should reappear.
Initially all markers appear correctly, when I apply the filter, everything works as expected, but when I uncheck the filter, I get an "Maximum update depth exceeded" error.
"use client";
import { AdvancedMarker, APIProvider, Map, useMap } from "@vis.gl/react-google-maps"
import { MarkerClusterer } from "@googlemaps/markerclusterer";
import type { Marker } from "@googlemaps/markerclusterer";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const MAP_ID = "xxx";
const API_KEY = "xxx";

type Point = google.maps.LatLngLiteral & {
    key: string,
    city: string
    isCapital: boolean,
};

const locations: Point[] = [
    {
        key: "0",
        city: "Austin",
        lat: 30.241241516441292,
        lng: -97.73378248930749,
        isCapital: true,
    },
    {
        key: "1",
        city: "San Antonio",
        lat: 29.517273972261396,
        lng: -98.44789382382311,
        isCapital: false,
    },
];

type MarkerFilter = "capital" | "all";

export default function Home() {
    const center = { lat: 30.241241516441292, lng: -97.73378248930749 };
    const zoom = 6;
    const [filterCapital, setFilterCapital] = useState(false);
    const [markerFilter, setMarkerFilter] = useState<MarkerFilter>("all");
    useEffect(() => {
        let val: MarkerFilter = "all";
        if (filterCapital) {
            val = "capital";
        }
        setMarkerFilter(() => val);
    }, [filterCapital]);
    return (
        <main>
            <div>
                <label>Capitals</label>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="capital"
                    checked={filterCapital}
                    onChange={(e) => setFilterCapital(() => e.target.checked)}
                />
            </div>
            <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}>
                <APIProvider apiKey={API_KEY}>
                    <Map mapId={MAP_ID} defaultCenter={center} defaultZoom={zoom}>
                        <Markers points={locations} filter={markerFilter}/>
                    </Map>
                </APIProvider>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}

type Props = { points: Point[], filter: MarkerFilter};

const Markers = ({ points, filter }: Props) => {
    const map = useMap();
    const [markers, setMarkers] = useState<{ [key: string]: Marker }>({});
    const clusterer = useRef<MarkerClusterer | null>(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!map) return;
        if (!clusterer.current) {
            clusterer.current = new MarkerClusterer({ map });
        }
    }, [ map ]);
    useEffect(() => {
        clusterer.current?.clearMarkers();
        clusterer.current?.addMarkers(Object.values(markers));
    }, [ markers ]);
    const setMarkerRef = (marker: Marker | null, key: string) => {
        if (marker && markers[key]) return;
        if (!marker && !markers[key]) return;
        setMarkers((prev) => {
            if (marker) {
                return { ...prev, [key]: marker };
            } else {
                const newMarkers = { ...prev };
                delete newMarkers[key];
                return newMarkers;
            }
        });
    }
    return (
        <>
            {points.map((point) => (
                (filter == "all" || (filter == "capital" && point.isCapital)) && <AdvancedMarker
                    key={point.key}
                    position={point}
                    ref={(marker) => setMarkerRef(marker, point.key)}>
                    <div>{point.city}</div>
                </AdvancedMarker>
            ))}
        </>
    );
}


The issue is this piece of code:
    const setMarkerRef = (marker: Marker | null, key: string) => {
        if (marker && markers[key]) return;
        if (!marker && !markers[key]) return;
        setMarkers((prev) => {
            if (marker) {
                return { ...prev, [key]: marker };
            } else {
                const newMarkers = { ...prev };
                delete newMarkers[key];
                return newMarkers;
            }
        });
    }

You can put a log here to see, it is running in a loop.

To understand why, let us reiterate when it should run.
This is a callback ref. Its body will execute when the component it is attached to mounts.
Here is an image from the docs:

The code conditionally renders AdvancedMarker:
    return (
        <>
            {points.map((point) => (
                (filter == "all" || (filter == "capital" && point.isCapital)) && <AdvancedMarker
                    key={point.key}
                    position={point}
                    ref={(marker) => setMarkerRef(marker, point.key)}>
                    <div>{point.city}</div>
                </AdvancedMarker>
            ))}
        </>
    );

Since the element AdvancedMarker is mounting and unmounting and then mounting again, setMarkerRef is being called again which in turn calls setMarkers.
If we look at setMarkers body, it creates a new object every time (as it should for valid state updates) and hence triggers another render.
If there is no other option than to use a state variable for markers, your best bet would be to set markers smartly. If you create a new object everytime, it WILL cause a rerender. Try to make use of previous state and not create that new object when the values are up to date.
Check if something like below works:
        setMarkers((prev) => {
            if (marker) { 
                if(prev[key]) return prev;
                return { ...prev, [key]: marker };
            } else { 
                if(!prev[key]) return prev; 
                const newMarkers = { ...prev };
                delete newMarkers[key];
                return newMarkers;
            }
        });


Here is a stackblitz where I have created a minimal reproduction of the issue. I have also fixed it using the same technique. You can see it going to infinite renders if you comment that line.

The proposed change in the updater function made perfect sense to me and looked really promising, unfortunately it didn't work. Thanks for the detailed explanation, i definitelly needed that since my react thinking is for sure not there yet. After changing the filter to not accept "all", so it's either capitals or non-capitals, it does swap the locations correctly. Which makes me think i messed up something either with the conditional printing of the markers or in the useEffect which updates the filter state. I will post an update when I get a chance to debug it.

Sure. Do try to put logs/debuggers in places to better understand what is running when. All the best. Let me know if I need to update anything. I hope the minimum repro helped.

@dan Btw, updated the stackblitz with the all condition, to indicate that it should also work
